# URL Rewriting not possible?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a website with this url :
http://www.example.com/stage?dept=01
I want transform this url to this
http://www.example.com/stage-ain.html

I want that new url override the standard html and it's become the only url available (for SEO).

I do this, but it's not ok :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^stage?dept=01$ stages-ain.html [R=301]
```

Have you an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of `RewriteRule` cannot match the query string. You have written a regex instead that matches the url `stagedept=01` and `stagdept=01`.

You want to use a `RewriteCond` instead. You could use the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable, but this will likely cause an infinite loop. Instead you probably want to match on `%{THE_REQUEST}`.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /stage\?dept=01
RewriteRule ^ stages-ain.html [R,L,QSD]
```

Change the `[R]` flag to `[R=301]` when you have tested everything works as expected. Always use the `L` flag with external redirects, unless you have a very good reason to continue rewriting, as this can cause some weird problems.

See [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a zero with url rewriting. Your solution give me this url :
www.example.com.ici/stages-ain.html?dept=01
I'm try to put a $ after .html in the rewrite rule bit i have a internal server error. How to remove ?dept=01 of the url ?
Thanks

Comment: Oops, my fault: Either add the `QSD` (query string discard) flag or add a `?` behind `.html`. Answer has been updated.

Comment: Sorry, but with QSD i have also an Internal Server Error :/

Comment: Then you are likely using an old version of Apache. The `QSD` flag was added in Apache 2.4.0. Use the other variant I suggested in my comment.

Comment: Ok for my apache version.
I use your second tips like this ? RewriteRule ^ stages-ain.html? [R,L]
And my url is always www.example.com.ici/stages-ain.html?dept=01
An idea ? (i'm sorry :/)

Comment: That should not happen with that rule. Try clearing your cache.

Comment: Yeaa,, it was my brower cache. Thank you very much !